# Using ray to speed up checking json files

Tags: python, json, ray

I have over a million json files, and I'm trying to find the fastest way to check first, if they load, and then, if there exists either `key_A`, `key_B`, or neither. I thought I might be able to use ray to speed up this process, but opening a file seems to fail with ray.

As a simplification, here's my attempt at just checking whether or not a file will load:

```
import ray
ray.init()

@ray.remote
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.good = 0
        self.bad = 0

    def increment(self, j):
        try:
            with open(j, 'r') as f:
                l = json.load(f)
            self.good += 1
        except: # all files end up here
            self.bad += 1 

    def read(self):
        return (self.good, self.bad)
    

counter = Counter.remote()
[counter.increment.remote(j) for j in json_paths]

futures = counter.read.remote()
print(ray.get(futures))
```

But I end up with `(0, len(json_paths))` as a result.

---

For reference, the slightly more complicated actual end goal I have is to check:

```
new, old, bad = 0,0,0

try:
    with open(json_path, 'r') as f:
        l = json.load(f)
    ann = l['frames']['FrameLabel']['annotations']
    first_object = ann[0][0]
except:
    bad += 1
    return

if 'object_category' in first_object:
    new += 1
elif 'category' in first_object:
    old += 1
else:
    bad += 1
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ray, but I'm thinking maybe it isn't shuttling the necessary over?

Comment: Did you check if ray is suitable for file access? It is supposed to be able to run on distributed systems as well.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a single machine or a cluster of nodes? It sounds like Ray isn't looking for the files where you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using Python for this at all, but for example [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

A command like

```
jq -c "[input_filename, (.frames.FrameLabel.annotations[0][0]|[.object_category,.category])]" good.json bad.json old.json
```

outputs

```
["good.json",["good",null]]
["bad.json",[null,null]]
["old.json",[null,"good"]]
```

for each of your categories of data, which will be significantly easier to parse.

You can use e.g. the GNU find tool, or if you're feeling fancy, `parallel`, to come up with the command lines to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python' built-in concurrent module instead to perform your task, which ray might not be best-suited for. Example:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
numThreads = 10

def checkFile(path):
    return True # parse and check here

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=numThreads) as pool:
    good = sum(pool.map(checkFile, json_paths))
bad = len(json_paths) - good
```